# Get all the keys of objects within another object with property value that matches the query

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, key-value

I have a nested object. I need to filter them out by property of the child object but only get the keys.

I have tried so far to first, inject a property **id** into each child object and assign the object's key as its value. Then proceed to filter the object, compare property if it will match with the query, then return the injected property **id**.

```
let test_obj = {
    A: {
        a: 1,
        b: 1,
    },
    B: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
    },
    C: {
        a: 1,
        b: 3,
    }
}

let identify = (e) => {
    for (e of Object.entries(e)){
        key = e[0];
        val = e[1];
        val.id = key;
        console.log(e);
    }
}

identify(test_obj);

let query = (test_obj,prop,val) => (Object.values(test_obj).filter(o => o[prop] == val).map(o=>o.id));
let result = query(test_obj,"b",2);

console.log(result)
```

It currently return my desired results, yet I feel like I cheated. Is there a way to do this without having to inject another property to determine the key? I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: *Please* use `var`, `let`, or `const` when declaring your variables - you don't want to implicitly declare global variables.

Comment: Also note that `val` will be equal to the last item in `test_obj`.

Comment: You want to query `test_obj` to return the main Object which has a certain key:val pair? For that you will need the key:val pair, so `query(test_obj, "b", 2)` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding an additional key, and then filtering values, you can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the keys like this instead:

```js
const test_obj = {
  A: {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
  },
  B: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  },
  C: {
    a: 1,
    b: 3,
  }
}

const query = (obj, prop, val) => Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k][prop] === val);

console.log(query(test_obj, "b", 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution is to use the `reduce` functionality, which you can (and always should) use if you find yourself using `filter` and `map`:

```
function findKeysForValue(test_obj, value) {
  return Object.entries(test_obj).reduce((myKeys, [objKey, outerValue]) => {
    if (Object.values(outerValue).find(nestedValue => nestedValue === value)) {
      return [...myKeys, objKey];
    }
    return myKeys;
  }, []);
}
```